# How can I stop compressed files being decompressed when I download them?

Tags: windows-7, browser, download

I've found that downloading certain gzip compressed files from our workplace's internal network causes the files to be decompressed as part of the download process. I don't want this to happen (they're linux kernel images). Can I stop it? This seems to happen in all web browsers I try, but not if I use wget.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's common to use GZip to [compress data sent over HTTP connections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_compression) so browsers will extract the data if the see the header `Content-Encoding: gzip`.  Almost certainly the server on your internal network is configured to send these files with both  `Content-Type: application/x-gzip` *and* `Content-Encoding: gzip` headers.  This is not a great set up on your server; there was some discussion among Firefox developers about how to deal with this situation but [they decided](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=448240) that if people wanted to do that with a server that was their problem :)

Your best bet is to fix your internal server - exactly how depends on which server you're using.  If you can't do that, you can try changing the `accept` headers in your browser ([Firefox instructions](http://forgetmenotes.blogspot.co.uk/2009/05/how-to-disable-gzip-compression-in.html)).  That might not work since not all servers will respect those, and you'll want to remember to change them back since they will slow down your browser on other sites.